# React.js Could onChange synthetic event break garbage collection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html, events, dom

In my application, I have some renderings of 3D models (using three.js)
Using the `onMouseMove` event on a canvas element, I calculate the current position of my mouse in terms of 3d space, and detects what models are near that position. 
I am doing this on the `onMouseMove` event attached to my `<canvas>` component.

I also use an `<input>` component of type `range`, to change the "search radius" for objects detection. I am using the `onChange` synthetic event on this component.

Everything works fine initially, but as soon as I use the input component, thus firing the `onChange` events, the application starts to lag. I went into the performance monitor in Chrome's DevTools and recorded a performance profile, and noticed that there is something weird happening to GC behaviour before and after the `onChange` events.

#### Screenshot of Chrome Devtools performance monitor

[image]

It seems like GC is working fine before the `onChange` events are fired, but once the events are fired, it changes its behaviour and does not show the "zigzag" pattern anymore.

And this is precisely where the app starts lagging, and all function calls take much longer than before.

Can anyone help me understand what is going on here and how to resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

#### Edit 1

Ok, so oddly enough, I tried the `react-input-range` package to replace the native JSX input element, and this behaviour is now gone. GC still continues to work in a "zigzag" pattern even after triggering the `onChange` events on the input. I do not know how the package dispatches events behind the scenes, but i suspect that there is something up with the event system in React that may potentially cause GC to behave strangely.

Here is a screenshot of the performance monitor in a same scenario, but now using the `react-input-range` package:

[image]

Comment: What are you doing in your `onChange` handler?

Comment: Nothing much. I am dispatching an action to store the value of the input in the store.